# exec('mysqldump') PHP Fiel gets deleted on godaddy server

Tags: php, exec

```
<?php    
exec('mysqldump --user=username --password=somepassword --host=somemysqlataserver.hostedresources.com databasename> file.sql');
?>
```

The above worked fine the first time - then the PHP file containing it - would mysteriously be deleted from the godaddy server.

The tech help people said - you aren't allowed to use the exec?
Is that true?
Why did it work in the first place then?

**What is the alternative using PHP?**

Comment: if you are on shared hosting then your abilities are limited, most probably they logging somehow all function which you run and detected `exec` call from some file then removed it automatically, or they have scanner of files that is why sometime it worked till they located it and removed automatically

Comment: Thanks - why do you think it is not allowed?

Comment: because of security reasons, as you can execute any `Linux` command in `exec`  and harm their system, so by that way you will crush sheared hosting on which build not only your website but other persons websites